# Negative test charge Electrostatics

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, charge, conventions

Will there be any significant change (if any) in the formulas of electrostatics, if we use a negative test charge in the derivation.  thanks for the help appreciate

Comment: Relevant: https://xkcd.com/567/

Answer (score 0):

The only thing which will happen is that there will be an extra negative sign in all your equations.